# Why parent Container constraints are respected by child Container when OverflowBox is provided?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Minimal code:

```dart
Widget build(_) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      width: 100, // 'A' width
      height: 30,
      child: OverflowBox(
        maxWidth: 400, // 'B' width
        child: Container(
          width: 200, // 'C' width
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

If you chang `A` width to `0`, you'll find the the width (`C`) of white `Container` decreases which shouldn't happen because I'm providing `OverflowBox` which seems to provide its own constraints to its child to let it overflow.

In my understanding, the constraints passed by 1st `Container` shouldn't have any impact on 2nd `Container` as long as `OverflowBox` provides its own max/min to it.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: So where is your question ?

Comment: @dm_tr The question is why 1st container's width is having impact onto the 2nd container's width.

Comment: You answered by youself. It's because of the OverflowBox. You can specify the width or the height of the 2nd Container. But these changes will make sense only if you are decreasing the size compared to the 1st Container constraints

Comment: `child: Center(
child: Container(
width: 100, /* width can be 0 too */
height: 100,  /* height can be 0 too */
color: Colors.red,
child: OverflowBox(
maxWidth: 300,
maxHeight: 300,
child: Container(
width: 2000,
height: 2000,
color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.5),
),
),
),
),` - isnt the orange box 3x bigger than red one?

Comment: @pskink Sir, it's bigger but the question is why the width of 1st container is playing any role at all in 2nd container's width, if you change the width of 1st container in your code from 100 to 0, you'll see the 2nd container width reduces by some margin (not by 100, but by some arbitrary number)

Comment: no, if you change 100 to 0 the big, orange box will still have size 300x300 - it does not change

Comment: @pskink Sir, you're right actually! The dimensions (300*300) does remain the same but I think the 100 to 0 (in 1st container) seems to add some padding/margin. I've edited the question with a screenshot to show that effect.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vQmnYqsfPD/

Comment: @pskink I'll check it, but here's one thing I like about you, you seem to be one of those rare to rare SO user who are extremely passionate, you've countless number of times helped me in fixing something which requires too much of detail. I really respect you sir !!!

Comment: @pskink Now I understood the problem, it's the alignment which was causing the confusion. In your `Stack`, if you change the `alignment` to say `Alignment.centerRight`, you'll find the dimensions of 2nd container are getting changed (which they aren't behind the scene, it's the alignment which tends to show that).

Comment: no, size is still 300x300 (even if you change to `Alignment.centerRight`) - add some padding to whole `Stack` and you will see (or use devtools - they have some kind of [widget browser](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector))

Comment: @pskink Yes, sir the size indeed is `300*300`, however the alignment drags the widget out of the screen, and it can be seen clearly with the padding as you suggested. Can you please write the answer (and you always turn my request down haha).

Comment: if you dont want your widget NOT to go out of the screen simply use `alignment: Alignment.centerRight` inside `OverflowBox` (by default it is "center")

Comment: @pskink Got that sir, thank you for all your efforts. I'll wait for you to answer it (haha) and if you don't write it, I'll write it myself (credit always goes to you!)

Comment: yep, better write a self answer then